# Best solution to remove horizontal scrollbar with img width of 100vw?

Tags: html, css

Setting the width of an `<img>` to 100vw causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear on the bottom of the viewport, and the only working solution I have found to get rid of the latter is to use *overflow-y: overlay;*. However, I have read that this solution isn't optimal. What's a better alternative?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal scroll had come up because this is only an issue on windows. On Mac or Android the scrollbars are placed on top of the content and disappear once you're done scrolling so they don't affect the view width.

If max-width: 100% is the width of the viewport without scrollbars, then you didn't need 100vw in the first place.

**You could just have use width: 100%** because the element doesn't have any positioned ancestor, so its reference is the body.

A simple solution in your case is by giving max-width: 100%.

**HTML would be like:**

```
<div class="box">
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

**Use this CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
    .box {
        width: 100vw;
        max-width:100%; // This is very Important.
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Scrollbars are included in the `vw` and `vh` so the scroll will be added to allow you to see beyond viewport. You can set `max-width: 100%` to remove scrollbar.

```
width: 100vw;
max-width :100%
```

Comment: or we simply set `width:100%`

Comment: When scrollbars start appearing I panic and start shoving `box-sizing: border-box;` and `overflow: hidden` everywhere 

Comment: @Felype and most of the time ````overflow:hidden```` works :D

Answer (score -1):

add:

```css
div{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

this will remove default `margin` and `padding`

Comment: This will not work, when using `100vh` or `100vw` it takes the full view window height/width.